# Home screens maxed out (oops)... now I can't edit?

Tags: home-screen, bugs, samsung-touchwiz

Someone was playing with my coworker's Samsung Galaxy Gio (Froyo), and added an eighth home screen. Now hitting Settings->Edit makes the phone crash, as does minimizing (pinching) on any home screen - in other words, there is no way to jump between home screens or delete the four or five screens she has no use for.

I'm thinking a home screen launcher app would be a workaround, but is there any way to actually recover her original home screen setup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding additional home screens is not a stock Android feature so I can't comment specifically, but clearing data for the launcher application should work.

Settings → Applications → Manage applications → Launcher (might be named differently) → Clear data

You will lose your current home screen configuration, of course, but this should take care of the crashes and allow rebuilding it.

Any method for fixing the actual problem without losing the data will necessarily be specific to that particular launcher application, and it sounds like you've tried to find that sort of thing already.

Comment: It'll almost certainly be called "TwLauncher" on a Samsung (short for TouchWiz their customized launcher that allows you to change the number of home screens).